# enable hovering after first click

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to enable ajax load after the first click from the user but it doesn't work

```
var auto = false;
if(auto){
$(document).on("mouseover","#load-more",function() {
    console.log(page)
   page=page+1;

   loadMoreData(page);

});
}

$(document).on("click","#load-more",function() {
    console.log(page)

   page=page+1;
   auto = true;
   loadMoreData(page);

});
```

all that I need to enable loading with hover after first click

Comment: what is the error? also, please attach your ajax code too

Comment: @user404 need to enable the first one after second meaning that if user clicked load mored first time next will need to hover not click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use `if(auto)` in `mouseover` event function  like this

```
var auto = false;

$(document).on("mouseover","#load-more",function() {
if(auto){
    console.log(page)
   page=page+1;

   loadMoreData(page);
}
});


$(document).on("click","#load-more",function() {
    console.log(page)

   page=page+1;
   auto = true;
   loadMoreData(page);

});
```

in your code in page load check `auto` and then don't return to that code to assign `mouseover` event 
and you can change your code to this

```
$(document).on("click","#load-more",function() {
    console.log(page)

   page=page+1;
   auto = true;
   loadMoreData(page);

   $(document).on("mouseover","#load-more",function() {
     console.log(page)
     page=page+1;

     loadMoreData(page);

   });


});
```

with last code you can't use `auto` variable